# How can I change a JButton Color upon keyTyped event?

Tags: java, swing, background, jbutton, keylistener

My project is about creating a virtual keyboard, and the buttons on that keyboard have to change their color as the user types the respective button on their keyboard.
ie if I type 'e', the letter 'e' on my virtual keyboard has to change its color.

To draw my keyboard I used a 2D JButton Array, and a 2D String array, to name the buttons and assign their respective label, then I added to each button a KeyListener interface, and in that interface I instructed the program to change the color of the button. Compiling it works fine for me but the actual color change doesn't work. Can someone help?
Here's the code

```
    private JButton spButton, oneButton, twoButton, threeButton, fourButton, fiveButton, sixButton, sevenButton, eightButton,
                nineButton, zeroButton, dashButton, equalsButton, bspButton, tabButton, qButton, wButton, eButton, 
                rButton, tButton, yButton, uButton, iButton, oButton, pButton, rBracketButton, lBracketButton, slashButton,
                capsButton, aButton, sButton, dButton, fButton, gButton, hButton, jButton, kButton, lButton, scButton, 
                sqButton, enterButton, lShiftButton, zButton, xButton, cButton, vButton, bButton, nButton, mButton, 
                commaButton, periodButton, bSlashButton, rShiftButton, upButton, spaceButton, leftButton, downButton, 
                rightButton;
private JButton [][] buttonArray = {{spButton, oneButton, twoButton, threeButton, fourButton, fiveButton, 
    sixButton,sevenButton, eightButton, nineButton, zeroButton, dashButton, equalsButton, bspButton},
                                    {tabButton, qButton, wButton, eButton, rButton, tButton, yButton, uButton, 
        iButton, oButton, pButton, rBracketButton, lBracketButton, slashButton},
                                    {capsButton, aButton, sButton, dButton, fButton, gButton, hButton,
            jButton, kButton, lButton, scButton,  sqButton, enterButton},
                                    {lShiftButton, zButton, xButton, cButton, vButton, bButton, nButton, mButton, 
                commaButton, periodButton, bSlashButton, rShiftButton, upButton},
                                    {spaceButton, leftButton, downButton, rightButton}};
private char pressed;


public constructor(){
addKeyListener(new KeyEventsHandler());
}
private class KeyEventsHandler implements KeyListener {

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

            pressed = e.getKeyChar();
                for (int row = 0; row < keyBoard.length; row ++){
                    for (int column = 0; column < keyBoard[row].length; column ++){
                        if (pressed==buttonArray[row][column].getName().toLowerCase().charAt(0))
                        buttonArray[row][column].setForeground(Color.RED);
                        keyboardPanel.repaint();
                    }
                }




        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

        }


}
```

thanks in advance guys

Comment: You do realize that you can just create a `Button` array, at least for the numbered buttons?

Comment: And it's not an OS issue, it's a L&F issue ;)

Comment: You most likely have problems with focus, so you never listen for the key events in the right place. You need to ensure that **all** focusable components of your GUI listen with your `KeyListener`. It would be much better to do this with Key Bindigs, like @Sage suggested.

Answer (score 3):

- I weren't paying attention but as got notified by @mKobel: as you are using array of a component like `JButton` which is from the family of *controlling component* does action, so we should register `ActionListener` using `addActionListener(ActionListener)` function or use [`Action`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) which is even higher level implementation.
- For other container component, [Try using Key Binding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead of `KeyListener`S: Key listeners have their place as a low-level interface to keyboard input, but for responding to individual keys key bindings are more appropriate and tend to result in more easily maintained code. Key listeners are also difficult if the key binding is to be active when the component doesn't have focus.
- Try making use of `e.getSource()` to get the source component of the event instead of using a `for` loop to detect such,

**Edit:**

To response the comment of @predi below:

> e.getSource() would return the component with keyboard focus in OPs
>   case, which is not very helpful. He needs to provide some sort of
>   mapping, which he did

Instead using of long sentence of words, i have decided to make an example code so that it can be copied and pasted to see instantly the power of Key bindings and `event.getSource()`. There are more other ideal option to do things simply.

```
GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(0, 4);
        jPanel1.setLayout(layout);

        Action action = new AbstractAction() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.err.println("Event generated for source: "+((JButton)e.getSource()).getName());
            }
        };

        for(int i=0 ;i<4; i++)
            for(int j=0; j<4; j++)
            {
                String key = ""+(char)('A' + i * 4 + j);
                JButton button = new JButton(key);
                button.setName(key);
                button.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(key), "doAction");
                button.getActionMap().put("doAction", action);
                jPanel1.add(button);
            }
```

Comment: JButton has implemented all mouse and key events, properly then there isn't reason to use KeyListener but SWing Action or 1. ActionListener, 2. 2nd point is start point, 1st is very wrong suggestion

Comment: @mKorbel, thank you. I weren't paying attention to his array of declaration was in hurry for a phone call :) . Updated the answer.

Comment: `e.getSource()` would return the component with keyboard focus in OPs case, which is not very helpful. He needs to provide some sort of mapping, which he did.

Comment: What if the OP wishes to restore button foreground to the default on key released, which one would expect of a virtual keyboard? I think he would be much or less forced to use `KeyListener` or Key Bindigs.

Comment: @predi, make your question clear. `e.getSource()` will give the source of the event and it is true for all the event listeners that exist. Key Binding can work on key release too. I am not sure what makes you to think that `e.getSource()` and Key Bindings are not usable to achieve OP's requirement and *were not very helpful.*- in fact they will be suggested from page to page by all the Swing answerer of StackOverflow.

Comment: I agree that your answer is generic when it comes to keys and swing, however the OP is dealing with a special case where the source of the event is irrelevant, regardless of whether he uses a `KeyListener` or Key Bindings. He needs to determine which key was pressed and match it to a proper component in his array, which is very unlikely to be the object returned by `e.getSource()`.

Comment: I see what you did there. Nice. I take back what I said about `e.getSource()`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how you might do what you wish to do with [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), to support my comment to your question. It's a bit iffy though. Not sure if using the map I use in the example is a good idea...but you could always implement action-per-keystroke code to make it type safe. It should get you started.

```java
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class VirtualKeyboard extends JFrame {

    private final JButton jbQ = new JButton("Q");
    private final JButton jbW = new JButton("W");
    private final JButton jbE = new JButton("E");
    private final JButton jbR = new JButton("R");
    private final JButton jbT = new JButton("T");
    private final JButton jbZ = new JButton("Z");

    private final Map<String, JButton> keymap = new HashMap<>();

    public VirtualKeyboard() {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        add(jbQ);
        add(jbW);
        add(jbE);
        add(jbR);
        add(jbT);
        add(jbZ);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        keymap.put("q", jbQ);
        keymap.put("w", jbW);
        keymap.put("e", jbE);
        keymap.put("r", jbR);
        keymap.put("t", jbT);
        keymap.put("z", jbZ);

        InputMap inputMap
                = getRootPane().getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT);
        ActionMap actionMap = getRootPane().getActionMap();
        actionMap.put("key-pressed-action", new KeyPressedAction());
        actionMap.put("key-released-action", new KeyReleasedAction());

        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("pressed Q"), "key-pressed-action");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released Q"), "key-released-action");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("pressed W"), "key-pressed-action");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released W"), "key-released-action");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("pressed E"), "key-pressed-action");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released E"), "key-released-action");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("pressed R"), "key-pressed-action");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released R"), "key-released-action");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("pressed T"), "key-pressed-action");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released T"), "key-released-action");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("pressed Z"), "key-pressed-action");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released Z"), "key-released-action");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new VirtualKeyboard().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private class KeyPressedAction extends AbstractAction {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JButton button = keymap.get(e.getActionCommand());
            if (button != null) {
                button.setForeground(Color.RED);
            }
        }

    }

    private class KeyReleasedAction extends AbstractAction {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JButton button = keymap.get(e.getActionCommand());
            if (button != null) {
                button.setForeground(UIManager.getColor("Button.foreground"));
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: @dou2abou, you should prefer the answer of Sage, since he demonstrates the same, but in a much more elegant way.